# Leiningen has problems building a working uberjar

Tags: build, clojure, jar, leiningen

We're trying to build our Clojure project with Leiningen. We've succeeded in creating an uberjar by doing the following:

preconditions:

- project.clj file lists dependencies
- `:main my-project.core` in project.clj
- a core.clj file with a `-main` function
- `(:gen-class :main true)` in core.clj

procedure:

- ran `lein test`; completed with no failures
- ran `lein deps`; completed successfully
- from project.clj's directory:  rain `lein uberjar`
- This created two jar files:  My-Project-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar, and My-Project-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.
- ran `java -jar BioClojure-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar`, which resulted in this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

My research into this problem has not been fruitful.  [Apparently](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/31), it's a known problem with no good solution.  I do not understand the answers there.

**What do we need to do to get our uberjar working?**

- determine which of our dependencies is causing the problem?
- remove dependencies from our project?
- compile the project some other way?
- patch leiningen?
- use the suggested command:  `zip *-standalone.jar -d META-INF/DUMMY.SF` (I have no idea what this does)
- do something with `:uberjar-exclusions` in the project.clj file? (if so, what?)

---

Lein and java versions:

```
$ lein version
Leiningen 1.6.1 on Java 1.6.0_26 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
```

---

Update: running the command suggested gives:

```
$ unzip -l BioClojure-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar | grep -i -e "\.sf"
 49911  08-27-09 15:57   META-INF/RCSB-PDB.SF
     0  03-23-10 08:21   META-INF/maven/net.sf.alxa/
     0  03-23-10 08:21   META-INF/maven/net.sf.alxa/jlatexmath/
   929  03-23-10 08:20   META-INF/maven/net.sf.alxa/jlatexmath/pom.xml
   115  03-21-10 14:01   META-INF/maven/net.sf.alxa/jlatexmath/pom.properties
175241  08-17-11 20:25   META-INF/SELFSIGN.SF
     0  09-21-09 06:45   META-INF/maven/net.sf.opencsv/
     0  09-21-09 06:45   META-INF/maven/net.sf.opencsv/opencsv/
  5510  09-21-09 06:44   META-INF/maven/net.sf.opencsv/opencsv/pom.xml
   106  09-21-09 06:45   META-INF/maven/net.sf.opencsv/opencsv/pom.properties
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My understanding from reading the comments in that issue is that your problem would go away if you add the following to your `project.clj`

```
:uberjar-exclusions [#"foo.sf"]
```

where `foo.sf` is the particular .sf file you want to ignore from the jar. You can determine this by running:

```
unzip -l BioClojure-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar | grep -i -e "\.sf"
```

The suggested `zip` command deletes the particular file from the jar (which is of the ZIP format).

Comment: @MattFenwick I believe you want to exclude `RCSB-PDB.SF` and `SELFSIGN.SF` only.