# Leiningen - way to automate removal of *.DSA and *.SF files (Clojure Maven)

Tags: maven, clojure, signed, leiningen, uberjar

I'm using Leiningen to automate the creation of a single 'uberjar' from several dependencies. (For a Web Start Application).

Some of the jar files are signed, and the uberjar process brings across their signature files (which don't match the new jar). I want to add my own self-signed cert and remove the old ones.

Is there an easy way in leiningen to remove these old signing files (or stop them being copied across)? I'm doing it as a manual step at present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [lein ticket #31](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/31). I submitted a patch, but if it isn't in the version you're using, you can put this in your project.clj for a fairly comprehensive ban on .sf files:

```
:uberjar-exclusions [#"(?i)^META-INF/[^/]*\.SF$"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was looking for:

```
:uberjar-exclusions [#"foo.sf"]
```

From here: [Leiningen has problems building a working uberjar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892244/leiningen-has-problems-building-a-working-uberjar)